# How to create a dictionary of which the value is @State?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding

I've tried the following (simplified extraction):

```
struct MyView : View {
    var names: [String]

    @State private var flags = [String : Bool]()

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
            Toggle(isOn: $flags[name]) { <== ERRORS
                ...
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            for name in names {
                flags[name] = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in three errors:

- `Cannot convert value of type 'Slice<Binding<[String : Bool]>>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'`
- `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Range<Binding<[String : Bool]>.Index>'`
- `Referencing subscript 'subscript(_:)' on 'Binding' requires that '[String : Bool]' conform to 'MutableCollection'`

Probably a silly question, but why doesn't `$flags[name]`, which is a dictionary, simply result in one value: a `Binding<Bool>`?

How can this be resolved?

Comment: I think you just need to create a simple struct with name and bool.

Comment: As it is now, nothing can make use of the State aka the dictionary anyway, except the view. You are better off, passing the dictionary with a binding, where the underlying dictionary will be hold in a Model or ViewModel. A parent view might take the Model (or ViewModel) and setup the binding and pass it to your MyView. The Binding's getter reads from the underlying model, and the setter calls a function into the model which modifies the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick work around to get this working: manually create the binding:

```swift
        
Toggle(isOn: .init(
    get: { flags[name] ?? false },
    set: { flags[name] = $0 }
)) { 
    // ...
}
```

I'm looking into it why $flags[name]doesn't result in a Binding. It might be related to `dictionary[key]` returning an `optional<value>` instead of the `value` directly.

Another hypothesis is, in Swift, that brackets are mostly syntax sugar to call the `subscript` function. A function cannot be bound to, as it's only read only and bindings need write access to modify the value. This also explains why you can't bind to an array element, but I'm not 100% sure on either answer and would be happy to edit this in favor of the community

Comment: Thanks, this already works, but does look a bit hacky.  Could you explain a bit why/how?

Comment: @meaning-matters edited the answer, see if that covers it! Feel free to ask questions :)